# SMTP Code Is Sending Email In Local Windows But Not In Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, email

I have set up the SMTP server in Windows Server 2012.

I have made sure it is running.

Putting a txt file in mailroot pickup folder is sending email.

The code is sending email in local Windows 7 computer.

I also set up SMTP in IIS 7.

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("saimanti.das@lahey.org", "saimanti.das@lahey.org");
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
 client.Port = 25;
 client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
 client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
 client.Host = "relaysmtp.lahey.org";
 mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
 mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
 client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Can you access the SMTP server from the machine? Is it's use IP restricted? Is the server on the same network? etc. etc

Comment: Basically this could be any of a number of reasons and the only person placed to solve this is you

Comment: What's _Windows 2012_? Did you mean _Windows Server 2012_? Also, please post the error you're getting (if any), or alternatively a description of what is happening.

Comment: Put a `try-catch` around the `client.Send`, and write the exception (if any) to a log file so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Does the SMTP server accept anonymous sends? If not you probably need to assign credentials `client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourusername", "yourpassword");`

Comment: Ho wto get the username and password of the System.Net.NetworkCredential? Yes I am using windows server 2012. I trued localhost and the ip address none worked. Code and the IIS server is on save computer.

Answer (score 0):

This was really not an issue of SMTP. SMTP was working. There was a bug in my code where I was not catching the IIS 8.0 instance.

Thanks fot your help and this site is really good.